# Password is not required when log in to ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: login, password

I am using ubuntu 14.04  LTS for a week only. First, there was a password. Then I made the setting 'log in without a password.' After 2 days I again made a password. It is required for authentication nd installing apps. But when I log in to ubuntu, its not needed ! I can log in without it. There's no option for password. Btw, I turned automatic login off, and changed the password several times but no result come out.  What can I do ?

Comment: my problem has been solved ! Thank u extreme to all ! :)

Comment: If the answer below solved the problem, please click the grey check mark and make it green, indicating the answer is correct. You may also write your own answer and mark it as correct. This will help others in the future. If the problem went away on its own, please delete the question, as it is unlikely to help anyone.

Answer (score 2):

Your account probably is in the nopasswdlogin group. Enter this command:

```
sudo gpasswd -d $USER nopasswdlogin
```

Enter it just the way it is. No need to replace anything. However, don't log in as root to do this because then `$USER` will not be your user name (like when you use your normal user account and `sudo`) but `root`.